# removing or configure app's feeds on facebook app ticker

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am developing a games app that using score api but somehow i dont wanna certain feeds from showing up on the canvas app ticker.Is there a way to configure an own feeds/hiding them totally in the app developer setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you post activity to Facebook if you don't want it to appear on Facebook? 
I'm not sure if this applies to the Scores and Achievements APIs, but in the new Open Graph APIs if you include `no_feed_story=1` it suppresses the activity from ticker and feed.

Comment: it is an auto feeds at the ticker.something like xxx is ranked 3 in xxx with 1000 points.

Comment: scores api only take one parameter that is the score itself:(

Comment: yes, i don't understand why you'd want to post a score if you don't want those stories, but i try posting with no_feed_story=1 and see if that works

Comment: hmmm...actually the reason being is to retrieve the user's friends who had done something on the app without retrieving from the database via the Score API.any other way of achieving this other than Achievement API as i just couldn't make it from some unknown errors

Comment: plus i saw that there is no way of retrieving friend's action on facebook documentation regarding Achievement API.So is there any other possible way?